# Package vignettes not available in R

Tags: r

I am building an R package.

I have an rmarkdown file at `vignettes/mydoc.Rmd`.

Using `devtools::build_vignettes()` results in files appearing at `inst/doc`.

No warnings or errors appear when I use `R CMD build .`.

However, when I use `vignette()` from within R, I do not see any vignette for the package.

My `DESCRIPTION` file includes:

```
Suggests: knitr,
    rmarkdown,
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: Did you run `devtools::use_vignette` or manually edit the `DESCRIPTION` file to say there is a vignette?

Comment: I only used `build_vignette()`. I'll try `use` after lunch.

Comment: `use_vignette()` didn't produce any changes to the `DESCRIPTION` file versus what I already had there. I've edited my question to show that.

Comment: Including the `inst/doc` directory in the Github repo did lead to the vignette being available. It's not clear to me why `R CMD INSTALL .` and `R CMD build .` don't create this directory.

Comment: I though you had the vignette in `inst/doc` already... github should be incidental to the process.

Comment: And `R CMD BUILD` makes a tarball, it doesn't modify your development directories, and `R CMD INSTALL` installs the package in your library, it also doesn't modify your development directories.

Comment: I'd assumed that either build or install would place the vignettes in the appropriate directory. So the development path is then `devtools::build_vignette()` followed by `R CMD BUILD`/`R CMD INSTALL`?

Comment: Which workflow? For development you can use just `devtools::install(..., build_vignettes = T)`. You really only need to build when you're ready to release to CRAN. At that point, I'd use `devtools::build(..., vignettes = T)` as a wrapper for `R CMD BUILD`, but that's just a preference.

Comment: Got it. If you'd care to try to craft an answer, I'm happy to accept one, and edit appropriately if it ends up being unclear vis-a-vis my situation.

Comment: Did you include `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}` and `%\VignetteIndexEntry{vignette-name}` at the top of the .Rmd file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear how/if you're installing in between steps. I'll quote from Hadley's *R Packages* website, the *Vignettes* chapter, mostly from the *Development Cycle* section:

> To create your first vignette, run:
>
> ```
> devtools::use_vignette("my-vignette")
> This will:
> ```
>
> 1. Create a vignettes/ directory.
> 2. Add the necessary dependencies to DESCRIPTION (i.e. it adds knitr to the Suggests and VignetteBuilder fields).
> 3. Draft a vignette, vignettes/my-vignette.Rmd.

The above can be done manually or via the `use_vignette()` command, but it does need to be done.

After authoring your vignette, it will need to be built.

> You can build all vignettes from the console with `devtools::build_vignettes()`, but this is rarely useful. Instead use `devtools::build()` to create a package bundle with the vignettes included. RStudio’s "Build & reload" does not build vignettes to save time. Similarly, `devtools::install_github()` (and friends) will not build vignettes by default because they’re time consuming and may require additional packages. You can force building with `devtools::install_github(build_vignettes = TRUE)`. This will also install all suggested packages.

I believe that `devtools::install()` will include any vignettes that are already built, the extra argument is only needed if you want rebuild them at the time of installation.

---

`R CMD BUILD` makes a tarball, it doesn't modify your development directories, and `R CMD INSTALL` installs the package in your library, it also doesn't modify your development directories.

For development you can use just `devtools::install(..., build_vignettes = T)` when you want to rebuild vignettes and install a package.

You really only need to build the package itself (generate zip or tarball depending on your system) when you're ready to release to CRAN. At that point, I'd use `devtools::build(..., vignettes = T)` as a wrapper for `R CMD BUILD`, but that's just a preference.

Comment: Indeed, I'd thought the vignettes were generated by `R CMD BUILD .` using `devtools::build(vignettes=TRUE)` works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing very erratic behaviour with

```
R CMD build myPackage
R CMD INSTALL myPackage
```

sometimes this installs the vignettes, and sometimes not.

devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE) seems like a more robust alternative. It also has the advantage of offering to update any outdated packages involved in the installation.